# Skipping a line of code if an image isn't selected

Tags: vb.net, image

If a user selects an image it will save the image as per the below code:

```
PictureBox1.Image.Save(PicFile, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

Now if the user decides not to select an image, is there a way to skip this code? I currently get the following error:

> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is what I've tried:

```
Dim opf As New OpenFileDialog 
opf.Filter = "Choose Image(.jpg;.png;*.gif)|*.jpg;*.png;*.gif" 
If opf.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then 
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(opf.FileName) 
End If 

Try 
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream 
    PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg) 
    Dim img As Byte() 
    img = ms.ToArray() 
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(img) 
Catch ex As Exception 
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString()) 
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now if the user decides not to select an image, is there a way to skip this code?

If by this you mean the user selects **Cancel**, then yes. Simply place the `Try[...]Catch` block into your `If` statement and it will only attempt the code if the user selects **Open**.

Something like this:

```
Dim opf As New OpenFileDialog 
opf.Filter = "Choose Image(.jpg;.png;*.gif)|*.jpg;*.png;*.gif" 

If opf.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then 
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(opf.FileName) 

    Try 
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream 
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg) 
        Dim img As Byte() 
        img = ms.ToArray() 
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(img) 
    Catch ex As Exception 
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString()) 
    End Try
End If
```

If you only wanted to skip certain bits of code you could do a check on `opf.FileName`. As an example:

```
If opf.FileName <> "" Then
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(opf.FileName)
End If
```